# Inequality of Weighted norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

I have a question about the weighted norm inequality:
The weighted norm of a vector $x\in R^{M\times N}$  is defined by:
 $\left \|  X\right \|_{w,*} = \sum_{_{i}}\left |w_{i}\sigma _{i}\left ( X \right )  \right |$
where $w_{i}$ denotes entries of the weighted matrix and $\sigma_{i}\left ( X \right )=\sqrt{\lambda _{i}\left ( X^{T}X \right )}$ stands for the singular values of X.

Lemma: $\forall A, B \in R^{M\times N} $ satisfies $ A^{T}B=0$, 
we have:
$\left \| A+B \right \|_{w,*}\geqslant \left \| A \right \|_{w,*}$

I have tried to prove the above lemma, but not success
Please help me do it.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The orthogonality condition $A^TB=0$ implies that 
$$\sigma_i^2(A+B)=\lambda_i((A+B)^T(A+B))=\lambda_i(A^TA+B^TB).$$ 
Since the matrices $A^TA$ and $B^TB$ are symmetric positive semi-definite, it follows from the [Weyl theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality) that 
$$\lambda_i(A^TA)\leq\lambda_i(A^TA+B^TB) \quad \Rightarrow \quad \sigma_i(A)\leq\sigma_i(A+B).$$ 
Now just plug these inequalities to your norm.